# Linked list code for deleting an item at a particular position

Tags: java, linked-list

I am working on Singly linked lists and have coded a function that will delete an element at a particular position in the linked list.

Problems I am facing is I am unable to delete an element if there is only one element left in the linked list.

Here is my code:

```
void deleteAtPosN(int position) {

    int i = 1;
    LinkedList temp = head;

    if (position <= 0)
        return;

    while (i < position - 1) {
        temp = temp.next;
        ++i;
    }

    if (temp == null) {
        System.out.println("list is empty");
    } else if (i == position) {
        temp = null;
    } else {
        LinkedList deleteElement = temp.next;
        temp.next = deleteElement.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume `head` points to the beginning of the list.  If you want to delete the first (0th index) element, what needs to happen to `head`?

Comment: @MFisherKDX Remove the reference of the first node

Comment: @BatCat apologies - I misread the question so answer deleted :)

Comment: You have an index issue

Comment: Let me use this comment to rant against linked lists, which are often part of computer science education, which makes people think they are useful in practise. Actually, in 9 out of 10 cases they should be replaced by ArrayLists.

Answer (score 1):

## Why your code does not work

When you get to the last item you set temp to null, but that does not affect the linked list in memory, it just changes your local copy to be equal to null.

## How to fix

You want to keep a reference to the previous element, and modify it's next, instead of keeping the current item

## Pseudocode

```
fun removeN(index) {
    var current = head
    var last = null
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        last = current
        current = current.next
        i++
    }
    if (last == null) {
        // We are at the head of the list
        head = current.next
    } else {
        last.next = current.next
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an iterative solution by @jrtapsell that keeps track of the `last` and the `current` pointers.  Here is a recursive solution that keeps track of all the `last` pointers via the recursive call stack.  The recursive solution is easier to understand and write, but the iterative solution is better IMO because it has O(1) extra memory overhead as opposed to O(N).

```
//zero based indexing, assumes position >= 0
public void deleteAtPosN(int position)
{
    head = deleteAtPosNHelper(head, position);
}

//assumes position >= 0
private LinkedList deleteAtPosNHelper(LinkedList current, int position)
{
    if (current == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else if (position == 0)
    {
        return current->next;
    }
    else
    {
        current->next = deleteAtPosHelper(current->next, --position);
        return current;
    }
}
```